# How To set up a Tag game in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

new poster here,sorry if this is a bad question. I want to set up a Tag game in Minecraft **BEDROCK**, but I've run into some walls.

Assume the tag game is played like this: someone has a nametag named something, let's say TagItem. When the nametag is thrown, I want it to increment a scoreboard value for all players who did not throw the nametag within 1 block. However, since theirs no NBT tags in Bedrock, I can't get the command to tag the thrower as `tagger`.

If their's a better way to set up this system, I'm all ears.

`/tag @e remove tagger`

`/tag @e[type=item,name="TagItem"] add tag`

`some magic to make the thrower be tagged Tagger`

`/execute @e[tag=tag] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players @e[r=2,type=player] TagList add 1`

Thanks in advance.